# How To Have Multiple Users Accessing Backend & Save Data?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm hoping someone can help explain this process in layman's terms, since I'm still "new" and learning.

I've built a basic content management system with a backend, and I'm trying to create a system where dozens of users can access a service, save data to their account, and recall that data at a later time if they choose.

Thus far I've got the login, registration, and forms (to save the data) complete. I'm just at a point where I don't know how to save this data in MySQL (using PHP by the way) so that dozens of users can all save data vs. just one.

Example being: Dozens of users access WordPress and can create posts, while not being able to see the other users posts on their account.

I understand how to setup one account to save data, just not multiple.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. If anyone has any guides/tutorials/recommended articles to read, I'd be incredibly grateful!

Comment: @beerwin I haven't tried anything yet since I really don't even know where to start. If someone could explain the process of what I needed to do, then I'd know where to more/less go from there I think.

Comment: http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/ ...

Comment: For a better grasp on MySQL: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql. Also, the PHP MySQL manual can help: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php.

Comment: If you like to do it by your self reade comment of Nikola. But have also a look at frameworks. http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Zend-Framework-Basic-Tutorial-P840.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a fairly important part in how PHP works.

Each separate user uses a different instance of your application. For example, if I enter and login into the application, and you do the same, we will have (for example), the variable $_SESSION set, but I will have `$_SESSION['idUser'] = 3`, and you will have `$_SESSION['idUser'] = 5`. They will not know of each others existence.

So basically, you need to think your application for a single user, with the appropriate restrictions. Meaning that, for example, if you want to create the edit profile page, you would use `$idUser = $_SESSION['idUser']` in your SQL queries to select/update/insert the appropriate information.

Here's a sample query:

```
// view users profile page
$idUser = intval($_SESSION['idUser']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = {$idUser}";

// edit profile checks/database update
$idUser = intval($_SESSION['idUser']);
$userData = $_POST['user']; // let's say all your inputs have a name="user[...]"
// !!! validation for the user data !!!
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET col1='{$userData[col1]}', col2='{$userData[col2]}' WHERE id = {$idUser}";
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you need further clarifications.

PS: Don't forget to properly escape your data before using it in SQL queries, and use either mysqli or PDO extensions (do NOT use mysql, since it is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version of PHP).

Comment: Vlad,

I do have a session start: <?php session_start(); if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>

Could you expand on how I would communicate the user IDs to the database?

I was thinking an easy "workaround" would be to have users login, then simply fill out the form and submit their data. That submission would have an ID (15 for example) associated with it, but where I'm getting lost is how I can associate that ID (15) with the user (3) who originally submitted it - while making sure that user (5) cannot see what 3 submitted on the "edit settings" page.

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: you create a table `users` - with a few columns (id, username, password, other fields). When a user loggs in with the correct user/pass combination, you set the session id to the id corresponding the that username. After that, you simply show all information by checking it with that user id. You don't have to worry about a user seeing information from another user, since he will not have the user id variable set in the session

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. Whenever a user registers they are added to my database ("users" table) with 5 fields (ID, username, e-mail, password, name). When that user then logs in, I'll give them a session ID based off their user ID from when they registered. At that point, they'll go to the submission page and enter in their information, which then will save to the "global_settings" table. Based off the session ID, it will also save an associated value (the user ID) which will then connect the database & saved information to the user who submitted it. Am I on the right track so far?

Comment: Everything is on the right track so far. One more thing - if you have 3-4 extra fields, you can add them in the `users` table. You should also check out the following tutorial (read up on one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many SQL relations): http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/

Comment: Alright great - thanks a ton so far Vlad. Going to get back to work and see if I can't get this figured out today. :)